# Does exiting function with return sooner have any practical value

Tags: php, if-statement, return

Let's assume I have these two functions:

```
function foo(int $a): void
{
    if ($a > 5) {
        doThis();
        return;
    }

    doThat();
}

function bar(int $a): void
{
    if ($a > 5) {
        doThis();
    } else {
        doThat();
    }
}
```

Is there any practical advantage of exiting the function rather than using `else` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there is no difference between the two piece of code in your question.

Sometimes returning sooner can improve readability of the function, because there are less nested statements.

**Opinion:** I do however not like returns half way down long functions. I prefer all my functions/methods to return something, and to do that at the end of the function. In classes, when I have nothing to return, I always do `return $this;`, so I can use [method chaining](https://riptutorial.com/php/example/2190/method-chaining-in-php).

Comment: For the opinion part, it becomes difficult during debugging if you only return at the end. Half way returns are ok to let you know that there is no further business down in the function.

Comment: @nice_dev: Yes, that's true, that's why it's an opinion. The real reason is that I'm simply used to my functions returning something at the end, so I might miss a return in the middle when I quickly scan the code. So if you like a return in the middle that's fine with me. Even worse, I have written functions that return early.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.